# Notepad regex replacing to be repeated as desired

Tags: regex, replace, nmm

I have a single line string as below

new---MyObject----adsdfg.

My regex

```
Find what: (.+)

Replace with: $1 \n$1\n$1
```

This will give me my desired ouput  as

new---MyObject----adsdfg.
new---MyObject----adsdfg.
new---MyObject----adsdfg.

But what if I wanted it to be repeated 50 times?

Should I replaced it with

```
$1 \n{50}
```

which isn't  working unfortunately,

Help will be appreciated ....

Comment: @JvdJ - but what if my editor doesn't support macro? I'm using nmm text editor which doesn't support it.

Comment: A one liner script can do such job.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there’s no support for your idea. But you can use factors of 50:

Replace `.*` successively with:

- `$0\n$0\n$0\n$0\n$0\n`
- `$0\n$0\n$0\n$0\n$0\n`
- `$0\n$0`

The 1<sup>st</sup> operation give you 5.
The 2<sup>nd</sup> gives you 25.
The 3<sup>rd</sup> gives you 50.

Note also the use of `$0` for the *whole* match.

Comment: Only repeated 12 times,  my text editor is (nmm text editor)  by maok for android installed from playstore...